# How do I add search engine into my pagination

Tags: php, html, css, mysqli, search-engine

I got my pagination working with a table, but I want a search engine in it, how can I add search engine into it? I got a simple search form in it, but don't know how to integrate into it.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Search</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<form method="get" action="index.php">
<label>Search:     <input type="text" name="query"/>
 <input type="submit" name = "search" value="search" />
</form>
<?php
include('db.php');

if (isset($_GET['page_no']) && $_GET['page_no']!="") {
    $page_no = $_GET['page_no'];
    } else {
        $page_no = 1;
        }

    $total_records_per_page = 10;
    $offset = ($page_no-1) * $total_records_per_page;
    $previous_page = $page_no - 1;
    $next_page = $page_no + 1;
    $adjacents = "2"; 

    $result_count = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) As total_records FROM `cases`");
    $total_records = mysqli_fetch_array($result_count);
    $total_records = $total_records['total_records'];
    $total_no_of_pages = ceil($total_records / $total_records_per_page);
    $second_last = $total_no_of_pages - 1; // total page minus 1

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `cases` LIMIT $offset, $total_records_per_page");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>
              <td>".$row['name']."</td>
              <td>".$row['email']."</td>
              <td>".$row['phone']."</td>
              <td>".$row['case']."</td>
              </tr>";
        }
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Look in SQL Where command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a search item into the sql query:

```
<form method="get" action="index.php">
    <!-- Show query item after page reloading -->
    <label>Search: <input type="text" name="query" value="<?php echo htmlentities(isset($_GET['query']) ? $_GET['query'] : ''); ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name = "search" value="search" />
</form>
<?php
include('db.php');

if (isset($_GET['page_no']) && $_GET['page_no']!="") {
    $page_no = $_GET['page_no'];
} else {
    $page_no = 1;
}

$where = '';
if (!empty($_GET['query'])) {
    //it is important to escape search item before query
    $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['query']);
    //there are can be any conditions
    //lets say you want to find user by name
    $where = "WHERE cases.name = '{$query}'";
}

//items for pager need be calculated with query too
$result_count = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) As total_records FROM `cases` {$where}");

$total_records = mysqli_fetch_array($result_count);
$total_records = $total_records['total_records'];
$total_no_of_pages = ceil($total_records / $total_records_per_page);
$second_last = $total_no_of_pages - 1; // total page minus 1

//add condition to data query
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `cases` {$where} LIMIT $offset, $total_records_per_page");
```

I recommend you to use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) with [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) because they are more compact and more safe.

Also please take a look to modern frameworks like [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8) or [symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html#gsc.tab=0) because they already have same functionality.